# Not found: TF GPU device with id 0 was not registered and segfault after that

Tags: python, tensorflow

Could you please help me to debug this problem. I tried building with several versions but I can't solve it.

My configuration:

**Hardware:** MacBook Pro 13,3 eGPU NVIDIA 1080

**Software:** 

macOS 10.13.6

NVIDIA Web Driver 387.10.10.10.40.105

CUDA Driver 396.148 

CUDA 9.1 Toolkit

cuDNN 7.0.5

Python 2.7

NCCL 2.1.15

Xcode 9.2

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.test.is_gpu_available()
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:859] OS X does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7335
pciBusID: 0000:46:00.0
totalMemory: 8.00GiB freeMemory: 2.32GiB
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 2025 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:46:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
True
```

When I try to run something I get this error messages with segfault in the end:

```
Filling queue with 20000 CIFAR images before starting to train. This will take a few minutes.
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:859] OS X does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7335
pciBusID: 0000:46:00.0
totalMemory: 8.00GiB freeMemory: 3.39GiB
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3118 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:46:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:127] Not found: TF GPU device with id 0 was not registered
Segmentation fault: 11
```

In other program, I tried to reduce per_process_gpu_memory_fraction and batch size so it crashed after first batch with the same error code.

Comment: I have same problem. My python is 3.6.5 and CUDA toolkit is 9.2, cuDNN is 7.1.